# Ngnix mask subdomain to URL from another subdomain with parameters

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Is it possible to mask a sub-domain to point to another sub-domain like so:
`sub.domain.com`to `sub2.domain.com/example/example2`.

I was able to sort of get this by using this nginx configuration:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
<!-- ssl_certificate goes here -->
server_name sub.domain.com;

rewrite ^/?$ https://sub2.domain.com/example/example2 permanent;
}
```

But the problem with this config is that when you go to sub.domain.com you are redirected to `sub2.domain.com/example/example2` instead of just masking the URL.

And if I go to `sub.domain.com/test` instead of going to `sub2.domain.com/example/example2/test` it just shows 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

Finally! I figured it out myself.

Instead of `rewrite` I had to use `proxy_pass`. And to extend the URL, I just needed to add a `/` to the end of URL:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass   https://sub2.domain.com/example/example2/; <-- Note the slash at the end
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP sub2.domain.com;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For sub2.domain.com;
   proxy_set_header Host sub2.domain.com;
}
```

Full code:

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot

   <!-- ssl_certificate goes here -->

   server_name sub.domain.com;

   location / {
      proxy_pass   https://sub2.domain.com/example/example2/;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP sub2.domain.com;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For sub2.domain.com;
      proxy_set_header Host sub2.domain.com;
   }

}
```